# Was the sefer Ein Yehosef ever reprinted?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

You can see the sefer Ein Yehosef here [ein yehosef](http://chabadlibrarybooks.com/45073) and here [ein yehosef 2](http://chabadlibrarybooks.com/19247). I want to know if it was ever reprinted and if not where I can purchase an original copy?

Answer (score 1):

You can order a hard copy reprint of the Sefer at the links you have listed for $21.00. If you are asking for an actual binding from that time period, you could try calling Bigeleisen's Bookstore in New York. They have some connections to individuals who might have an original.